# TypeError: text.select is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement copy to clipboard feature using js. 
I have a table:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td id="kord">(35|154)</td>
                <td id="gorj">15</td>
                <td>3,6</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="copyKord()">Kopiraj</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="copyGorj()">Kopiraj</button></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

My js function:

```
    function copyKord(){
    var text = document.getElementById("kord").innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

So when i press the button i get an error "TypeError: text.select is not a function at copyKord"
when i console.log the variable it shows the text. I tried using textarea insted of a td element and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `navigator.clipboard.writeText` to perform `copy` action.

```js
function copyKord(){
    var text = document.getElementById("kord").innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}

function copyGorj() {
  var text = document.getElementById("gorj").innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td id="kord">(35|154)</td>
                <td id="gorj">15</td>
                <td>3,6</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="copyKord()">Kopiraj</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="copyGorj()">Kopiraj</button></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your snippet throws error when we click on button. Please check and correct

Comment: On the attached code, only func for first `Kopiraj` button was available. I will add func for second `Kopiraj` button now.

Comment: navigator.clipboard is still working draft and may not be supported in all browser, so be mindful for cross browser compatibility